# Is there a good SharePoint file browser for React v18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, file-browser

I have been using [@microsoft/file-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/file-browser) (which is an unmaintained, closed source, multiple years old package for react 16.x) for some time now.

Now I have started a new project using React 18 and can not find any good file browsers.

**My goal is to have a native-looking SharePoint integration in my React application without having to manually query folders, files and such**.

Using Fluent UI to build a custom solution is not an option right now because it lacks React 18 support and takes significant resources to do it well.

Are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: how about the microsoft graph toolkit  specifically the mgt-file-list

https://mgt.dev/?path=/story/components-mgt-file-list--file-list

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a custom port of [spfx-controls-react](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react) library for this (extracted the pieces related to [filePicker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/FilePicker/) and just use it separately). I had to make a custom port so the library can be used outside SharePoint (no SPFx/webpart context needed).